# Haskell Location Definition "No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’"

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I'm getting the error "**No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’**", from inside a local definition in a function I'm trying to make which determines how many of the (three) given integers are above the average of all of the given integers. So I've created a local definition inside the function to calculate the average so I can then use it for guard checks. I've used the same code in a separate definition (in another file) to calculate the average and it works. I've tried putting the "**fromIntegral**" function call in different places but it's not working, where am I going wrong?

Here's the code:

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c
    | a > average && b > average = 2
    | a > average && c > average = 2
    | b > average && c > average = 2
    | a > average = 1
    | b > average = 1
    | c > average = 1
    | otherwise = 0
                where
                average = fromIntegral (a + b + c) / 3
```

The error is being flagged up on the last line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaner version of the solution you came up with:

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c
    | a' > average && b' > average = 2
    | a' > average && c' > average = 2
    | b' > average && c' > average = 2
    | a' > average = 1
    | b' > average = 1
    | c' > average = 1
    | otherwise = 0
  where
    average = a' + b' + c' / 3
    a' = fromIntegral a
    b' = fromIntegral b
    c' = fromIntegral c
```

You can simplify this even further to:

```
howManyAboveAverage a b c = length (filter (> average) [a', b', c'])
  where
    average = a' + b' + c' / 3
    a' = fromIntegral a
    b' = fromIntegral b
    c' = fromIntegral c
```

Comment: Thanks that does look like a cleaner way of doing it. I'll check it later today.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing `a` (which is an `Int`) and `average` (which is `Fractional a => a`). Since `(>) :: a -> a Bool`, GHC presumes that `average` is also an `Int`, which doesn't work. You either need to change `average` to `Int` (for example via `round`) or `a`, `b` and `c` to `Double` or `Float`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but that doesn't really answer the question. I need a + b + c to be divided by 3, so I need the answer to be in a float format.

Comment: @EM-Creations: Sorry, misread your question. The problem lies in the comparison.

Comment: I think I've managed to fix it by sticking "fromIntegral" in front of every parameter before comparing it to the average, thanks. I'll post up the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also compare integers instead. The idea is that `x < (a + b + c)/3` is equivalent to `3*x < a + b + c`.

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c
    | gti a av && gti b av = 2
    | gti a av && gti c av = 2
    | gti b av && gti c av = 2
    | gti a av = 1
    | gti b av = 1
    | gti c av = 1
    | otherwise = 0
        where 
            av = a + b + c
            gti x m = 3*x > m
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this by adding "fromIntegral" in front of any parameter that was compared to the average.

New (working) code:

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c
    | fromIntegral a > average && fromIntegral b > average = 2
    | fromIntegral a > average && fromIntegral c > average = 2
    | fromIntegral b > average && fromIntegral c > average = 2
    | fromIntegral a > average = 1
    | fromIntegral b > average = 1
    | fromIntegral c > average = 1
    | otherwise = 0
                where
                average = fromIntegral (a + b + c) / 3
```

It looks a bit messy / cumbersome so if anyone has any other (cleaner) suggestions please let me know.